# Laurent Series of $\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^2}$

Tags: laurent-series

Expanded to the Laurent Series at the deleted neighbourhood of $$z=i$$
and try to give the Convergence range

I'm trying to make $$\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^2}=\bigg(\frac{-1}{2z}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{1+ z^2 }\bigg)\text {'}$$

$$\frac{1}{1+ z^2}={1-z^2+z^4-z^6...}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(-1)^ n(z^{2n})}$$

$$\bigg(\frac{1}{1+ z^2 }\bigg)\text {'}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(2n)(-1)^ n(z^{2n-1})}$$

so that

$$\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^2}=\bigg(\frac{-1}{2z}\bigg)\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(2n)(-1)^ n(z^{2n-1})}$$

$$=-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} {(n)(-1)^n(z^{2n-2})}$$
But it seems not right...

Comment: Please learn use of mathjax for question asking: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Are you trying to compute a Laurent series or an integral?  It's hard to see what the first line has to do with the third line.

Comment: Do you mean $|z|>1$ or $|z|<1$?

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with Laurent series.  You haven't even told us the center--is it $i$ or $-i$?  It looks more like you are trying to compute a Taylor series.  Please clarify your question.

Comment: @RhysHughes Wow thank you，i am trying to learn it！ it's really useful !

Comment: @saulspatz i am so sorry, i have not made it clear, and now i learn to use mathjax, it's better

Comment: @GuusPalmer sorry for say that, well, it's at the deleted neighbourhood of point &z=i$

Comment: @saulspatz sorry for that, i am just started to use Stack Exchange,  it is at the deleted neighbourhood of point $z=i$

Comment: @awc789 Then you should have powers of $z-i$ shouldn't you?  Everything you are doing is about $z=0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really can't follow what you are doing.  You start by saying, "I'm trying to make $$\frac{1}{(1+z^2)^2}=\bigg(\frac{-1}{2z}\bigg)\bigg(\frac{1}{1+ z^2 }\bigg),$$ but you surely know that this isn't a true statement.  I also don't see what it has to do with what follows.

Let me get you started: $$\frac{1}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2(z-i)^2}  
$$
Now $1/(z+i)^2$ is analytic at $z=i$ and so can be developed in a Taylor series about $z=i$.  Once you do this, you can simply multiply the series by $1/(z-i)^2$ to get the desired Laurent series.

Comment: wowowwoowowo i understand！so appreciate！

Comment: @awc789 Glad to help out.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Series for $\frac{1}{1+z^2}$ is $\frac{1}{1-(-z^2)}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}(-z^2)^k$.

Comment: This is the series for $\exp(-z^2)$ if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Oops, you're right.

Comment: @GuusPalmer sorry i have just using mathjax to clarify it